# iOS SwiftUI - disable ignoring the safe area

Tags: ios, swiftui

I read tons of questions about how to make the app ignore the safe area, but when I create a new app then the status bar space is ignored anyway without

```
.ignoresSafeArea()
```

Why is that? I don't want it to be ignored!

This is all I have:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
            
            Spacer()
            
        }
        .frame(width: 300)
        .background(Color.teal)
        

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[the result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8rkx.png)

Comment: ״*By default* your SwiftUI views will mostly stay inside the safe area״.  https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-place-content-outside-the-safe-area

Comment: Why does .ignoresSafeArea() exist then and what's the solution? I don't want any content to be visible behind the status bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it, inside a ZStack:

```
GeometryReader { reader in
    Color.white
        .frame(height: reader.safeAreaInsets.top, alignment: .top)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
}
```

Comment: Late 2023 update: for me it doesn't work perfectly. It puts a very small "padding" around the used color. However, if I change the order of the modifiers (e.g. first .ignoreSafeArea(), and then .frame(height: ...), it works like charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so:

```
VStack {
    
    Color.teal
        .overlay {
            Text("Hello World!")
        }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this modifier:

```
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

if you don't want everything you can choose : .top, .bottom, .vertical, .horizontal,...